# DraggableScrollableSheet doesn't expand/collapse in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm building an app in flutter and I finally got the app to run, but for some reason, the DraggableScrollableSheet doesn't expand nor collapse.
I added a SingleChildScrollView, but it only makes whatever is inside the sheet scrollable but the sheet itself is basically "frozen".

Solutions I tried:

1. Using a ScrollView but it also didn't work as expected.
2. Removing the Expanded widget but I get a constraints error.

**My code:**

```
Sacffold(
///....
body: column (
 children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 128,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
                  child: Text(
                    //...
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  //...
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: 0.6,
              minChildSize: 0.2,
              maxChildSize: 1.0,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        //...
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 82,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              //...
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child:
                                      Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        0, 10, 0, 15),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Center(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                            child: Text(
                                             //...
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          //...
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        0, 10, 0, 15),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          child: Text(
                                            //...
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          //...
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            //...
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run the app on windows, but after doing a lot of research and testing, I found out the DraggableScrollableSheet **doesn't work on windows**, **it only works on android/ios**. I ran the app on an android emulator and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I kept the question because I found a lot of people were facing the same problem.